# Set background image for launchscreen.xib in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, user-interface

I need to set a background color or background image in my iOS application's launch screen. I was wondering if there was a code similar to:

```
self.view.backgroundcolor=[UIColor redColor];
```

Thank you

Comment: you can set your own launch image from image.axassets

Comment: Please look at this previously asked question at SO [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772862/ios-8-background-gradient-for-launch-screen-file

Comment: Want to set background color or Background Images? If you want to set background image, Just refere [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624085/splash-screen-for-ios-in-xcode-6-2/29624267#29624173)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to set background image for launch screen than there is two way:

1. Use `image.axassets` and add new LaunchImage set in it.
2. You can add `UIImageView` in `LaunchScreen.xib` and set image to it.

If you want to set background colour for launch image than add `UIView` in `LaunchScreen.xib` and set `backgroundColor` propertity of it.

Both way is easy but I preferred to go with image.axassets LunchImage set.

Note: If you use `image.axassets` LaunchImage than do not forget to migrate this set with application.

Comment: LaunchImages are deprecated