# How to set linear gradient to background of LaunchScreen.xib in iOS

Tags: ios, background, xib, linear-gradients, launch-screen

Is there any way to set linear gradient to background of LaunchScreen.xib in iOS? Something like `background="linear-gradient(#000000, #123456)"`?

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" background="...">
    <rect key="frame" width="753" height="867"/>
</view>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 - Background gradient for launch screen file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772862/ios-8-background-gradient-for-launch-screen-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't add custom code on LaunchScreen, so the alternative to achieve this is to use an ImageView

Try to look at [iOS 8 - Background gradient for launch screen file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772862/ios-8-background-gradient-for-launch-screen-file)

Answer (score 19):

You can create a vector image (pdf) with a gradient, add an ImageView to launchscreen and set that vector as the image.

If the image doesn't show up, clear the Xcode cache, restart Xcode, delete the app from your device, restart the device, and then it should show up.

Comment: This answer is awesome!